# FileNames[] perfomance in mathematica 8.0 and 11.3

Tags: files-and-directories, windows

OS - Windows.
I do the following code in both Mathematica 8.0 and 11.3.

```
In[15]:= t = FileNames["*", "Z:\\Constaint_5_min\\SPP\\Archive\\"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

"Z:\" - LAN connected SSD.

The output in 8.0:

```
Out[15]= {4.5074307, Null}
```

The output in 11:

```
Out[]= {434.354, Null}
```

As you can see it takes about 5 seconds in math 8 and 6.5 mins in 11.
11.3 - clean installation.
8 - I added to kernel/init.m the following code:

```
<<JLink`;
InstallJava[];
ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "java", JVMArguments -> "-Xmx512m"]
```

So the question is why does it happen? And how can I fix this?

Comment: I've tried adding <<JLink code to 11 math. It didnt help.

Comment: You can use `AbsoluteTiming` to measure execution time. Its output is much clearer, and people here are used to it. Your post might get more attention with that format. Please also be specific about versions, 11.0, 11.1, etc.?

Comment: On macOS, the performance seems reasonable http://i.stack.imgur.com/HNZzt.png I do not have 8.0 or 9.0 to test in. I compared 10.0 and 11.3.

Comment: Can you re-do the test with `AbsoluteTiming`, and repeat the test *twice* in *both* versions?  Please post all four timing (two for each version), and please do the four tests one after the other.  What I observe on macOS is that the first time I use `FileNames[]` on a directory, it is several times slower than on subsequent times. E.g. the first time it is 2.9 seconds, second time is it only 0.6 seconds *even if two tests are done in different versions of Mathematica*. I assume some caching is going on at the OS level.

Comment: What I suspect might have happened is that you ran the command in 11.x first. It was slow. But the OS has cached some results. Thus the second try (in 8.0) was much faster.

Comment: I've tried running this code several times and timings are always about 6s for 8.0 and 6 min for 11.3. I've tried it on two another pc connected to the same disk Z - the problem is still there.

Comment: Then I suggest contacting Wolfram Support about this (with full information about your setup: OS, OS version, how the Z: drive is mounted, etc.)  As a workaround, I would try to use the `dir` command, and parse its output. I am not on Windows, so I cannot test this, but `Import["!dir Z:\\", "String"]` might work. If it does not, you will need to find a way to run `dir` within `cmd`, e.g. `cmd /c dir` or similar (I don't remember the details).

Comment: I've tried same code on my mac air connected to same lan disk with math 10.0.1 and it takes 25s. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you open PowerShell and `cd` to the `Z:` drive and run this command, what timing do you get: `Measure-Command { dir }` ... Second question: does 11.3 speed up while you have the Powershell still open at this point?